# Is there a standard phone number in Kenya to call a directory service?

Tags: communication, africa, emergencies, kenya

In the United States, it's possible in most places to dial 0 (EDIT: 411) for a directory.

Is that the case in Kenya? If not, is there a different number that serves the same purpose?

(This is in relation to future plans. I want to be clear that I am not in Kenya right now. I'm just trying to be prepared.)

Comment: I haven't used them, but this page suggests at least three providers have directory enquiries numbers https://www.fodors.com/world/africa-and-middle-east/kenya/travel-tips/communications-268437290

Comment: In the US, it's 411 for directory assistance. 0 is for operator assistance in placing calls. It is increasingly common to find one or both don't work, particularly for corporate phone systems, [VoIP providers and cell phones](https://abc7.com/411-out-of-service-att-customers-landlines/12671256/). And even if it does work, it's [$3](https://www.t-mobile.com/support/plans-features/calling-services#steps3) for something you could have Googled.

Comment: @user71659 thanks -- I've updated the question to reflect your correction. From what I've seen, in parts of Kenya, there are many businesses that do not have a presence on Google.

Comment: Kenya is more oriented to mobile phones over landlines than the US, and directory enquiries may therefore not always be able to help for contacting individuals. (Hotels and large businesses may have landlines.)

Comment: @MayorofthePlattenbaus businesses you would not be able to find on Google or Google Maps and which are listed in the phone directory? That would be interesting. Do you have any examples?

Comment: @jcaron good question. I've seen several churches and small shops that don't have Google phone listings, but as for whether they're in the directory, I can't test that unless I have a directory number :-D

Comment: @MayorofthePlattenbaus Have you checked https://www.yellowpageskenya.com ?